# Setting a map based projection in D3 with leaflet on Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js, leaflet

I've been trying to move a JS project that uses D3 to draw SVG elements on top of a leaflet map using geo-referenced data to Angular.

So far I've created a component that will hold the interactive map and while trying to create a d3Path object I ran into a problem apparently because when doing so TypeScript is not able to recognize that the `this` keyword is meant to reference the projection object instead of the component.

This is the conflicting code:

```js
// Function on class body
function projectPoint(x, y) {
  var point = this.map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
  this.stream.point(point.x, point.y); // This line is marked as error
}

// This inside another function
transform = d3.geoTransform({
  point: projectPoint
});

d3Path = d3.geoPath().projection(transform);
```

Which is all basically the same found on the documentation. What do you think I could be doing/understanding wrong?

(Also, I'm kind of new to TypeScript and Angular so I'm not entirely sure why I must add `var` to values inside a function, otherwise, it marks it as an error)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `that` variable outside of the function and then use it as `this`. With this workaround the `this` reference is no more from the projection.

```
var that = this;
function projectPoint(x, y) {
  var point = that.map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
  that.stream.point(point.x, point.y); // This line is marked as error
}
```

Comment: But I need the opposite, I need `this` to reference the projection, not the angular component.

Comment: Oh sorry, then I can't help you